# Can someone please explain me that in java why 0.6 is <0.6f but 0.7is >=0.7f

Tags: java

Can someone please explain me  that in java why

```
     if(0.6 <= 0.6f ) System.out.printf("true");
     else System.out.printf("false");
```

this PRINTS true
but

```
    if(0.7 <= 0.7f ) System.out.printf("true");
    else  System.out.printf("false");
```

this PRINTS false

Is it related to IEEE 754 standards when floating point number is converted to double for comparision?

can someone explain it in detail the exact working?

Comment: What's with the "is" part in your code?

Comment: This has to do with the way that floating-point numbers are stored in Java. If you want precise numbers, use the class java.math.BigDecimal.

Comment: Does it actually compile? Never ever seen `is` in Java used that way.

Comment: The short answer is that floating-point numbers are not represented precisely. If you need to compare floats to each other, use `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @HenryKeiter: floating point numbers *are* represented precisely in themselves - they're just not a precise representation of a value such as 0.7. It's the conversion from 0.7 to "the closest `double` representation" which is losing information. Note that BigDecimal is also a floating-point type - it's just that it's a floating *decimal* point instead of a floating *binary* point.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, sorry for my imprecision. I meant what you said :)

Comment: If 0.6 and 0.6f were the same value why would you need two literals? ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure - it's just a matter of understanding that *none* of 0.6, 0.6f, 0.7 and 0.7f are those *exact* values. They're the closest representable approximations in the appropriate type. The exact values which are stored for those 4 values are:

```
0.6f => 0.60000002384185791015625
0.6  => 0.59999999999999997779553950749686919152736663818359375
0.7f => 0.699999988079071044921875
0.7  => 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875
```

With that information, it's clear why you're getting the results you are.

To think of it another way, imagine you had two *decimal* floating point types, one with 4 digits of precision and one with 8 digits of precision. Now let's look at how 1/3 and 2/3 would be represented:

```
1/3, 4dp => 0.3333
1/3, 8dp => 0.33333333
2/3, 4dp => 0.6667
2/3, 8dp => 0.66666667
```

So in this case the lower-precision value is smaller than the higher-precision one for 1/3, but that's reversed for 2/3. It's the same sort of thing for `float` and `double`, just in binary.

Comment: Thank you . I understand that ,but how can i simply tell what will be the result by just looking at the code ?

Comment: @user2410495: You can't just do it by inspection, unless you're able to do the maths in your head to work out what the binary representations will be. Sometimes the nearest `float` will be greater than the nearest `double`, sometimes it'll be smaller. Why is that important to you anyway?